# UMAP incompatible bytecode version

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cpython

I have trained a cluster model using Scikit-learn pipeline and [UMAP Learning](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

My model architecture is:

```
transformer = Pipeline([("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy= "constant", fill_value= 0)),
                        ("scaler",StandardScaler())),
                       ("proyection",UMAP(n_components = 3, random_state = 1990))]).fit(X)


model_iso = Pipeline([("scaler", transformer),
                  ("cluster",GaussianMixture(random_state= 1990, n_components= 3))]).fit(X)
```

Then I persist my model with:

```
pickle.dump(model_iso, gzip.open(model_path, "wb"))
```

Everything works fine locally, but I have deployed a lambda using AWS, and when testing my lambda passing it a payload I receive the following Error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "incompatible bytecode version",
  "errorType": "RuntimeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/index.py\", line 37, in handler\n    response = main(event, context)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/src/app.py\", line 51, in main\n    model = InvoicingClusterProfilingPM(payload)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/src/model.py\", line 45, in __init__\n    self.get_model()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/src/model.py\", line 178, in get_model\n    self.estimator = pickle.load(model_path)\n",
    "  File \"/tmp/sls-py-req/numba/core/serialize.py\", line 208, in _unpickle__CustomPickled\n    ctor, states = loads(serialized)\n",
    "  File \"/tmp/sls-py-req/numba/core/serialize.py\", line 112, in _rebuild_function\n    code = _rebuild_code(*code_reduced)\n",
    "  File \"/tmp/sls-py-req/numba/core/serialize.py\", line 132, in _rebuild_code\n    raise RuntimeError(\"incompatible bytecode version\")\n"
  ]
}
```

I have check [this](https://github.com/josephsdavid/N2D/issues/8) and [this](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap/issues/473#issuecomment-675340411) issues on Github but sadly, none of them have helped me with my problem

Can anyone help me on this? I would really appreciate it

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Part of what you have pickled is a compiled Python function, and Python's compiled  bytecode is not compatible between versions.  That's a tricky problem.  I don't know whether it will be possible for you to extract only the data without the functions.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I understood correctly, you mean that I used .fit in my transformer object?

Comment: I think I misdiagnosed this.  The error is being generated by the `numba` module.  Are you using that in an attempt at optimization?  `numba` generated compiled byte code for Numpy functions, and the version numbers must match.  Can you check the version of `numba` on both systems?

Comment: Oh I really appreciate this, I have numba==0.53.1 in my local machine, how can I check the version of numba in my aws lambda? (sorry if this is very basic question)

Comment: I don't know the mechanics of lambdas.  Usually, you should be able to run a file with `import numba` / `print(numba.__version__)`.  Unless you can ask `numba` to back off to an earlier bytecode version, you may have to skip `numba` for your lambda.